# Transfer measurements from Android OS to a database

Tags: android, sockets

In my project, I have an RFID device, electric weight, kit [Samsung S3C6410 ARM11](http://www.arm.com/community/partners/display_product/rw/ProductId/2644/) with Android OS and a PC.

Data is received from the RFID device, electric weight that saves data into a text file on an SD card.

I want to create an app that can get data and transfer it to a PC by wi-fi.

My data is such as: ID and weight.

My problem is how to get data from two different addresses (address of text file) and sending it in the direction of the PC. And can I use MySQL for showing it on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup on the PC an `Apache` webserver with php support (or anything other language that has strong support of DBs) and create a very simple .php page containing a form with the fields ID and weight, that will be stored in a MySQL DB.

The Android will only has to create a [HttpClientConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpClientConnection.html) and with the appropriate way, to submit the data to the form above.

Comment: thank you! my data is stored in two different places but they don't transfer to pc in same time.example : the first new data in file 1.text would updated and transfer to pc then new data in file 2.txt would also updated and transfer to pc.So i think my problem is how to create two connection to two address in sd card and transfer them. how can solve this problem ?

Comment: But why do you need two connections? When the data from the second file are ready just upload them using the a single connection, perhaps the same of the first file. Sorry if I understand something wrong...

Comment: thank you...i think because i must get data from two different address so i have two different address link.i must create two socket line for connect with two these link.I think my data will use single connection for connect with pc but i don't know if i call two socket function for connect with these data.Is that true ?

Comment: Ok now I think that I understand what you are saying. You have two or more Android phones, and you do not now how the *PC* will handle these multiple connections. Am I right? If yes, my answer solves your problem because Apache handles multiple connections. If you do not want to follow the answer and you want to create your own server at the PC, you should start looking for multi-threaded TCP serves. There are many examples at the Internet that you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

> And can I use MySQL for showing it on the PC?

MySQL is a database and has nothing to do with 'showing data' except for the fact that it stores it. Presentation is controlled by HTML/JS (on a browser) or whatever your favorite GUI toolkit is on the desktop.

Regarding your question, I suggest you learn about a few topics to further your understanding of what you want to do and how to solve it:

1. Computer Networking - IP Addresses, TCP, IP, DNS, HTTP, RESTful WebServices
2. Apache, MySQL, PHP & Linux

Basically, a socket is just a simple connection between two devices. What you're trying to do is unnecessarily complicated by the fact that you want to use raw sockets to talk to the computer. One of the many solutions here is to:

1. Setup a WebService on a computer that will write to a MySQL DB all the measurements you're transferring.
2. On the Android devices, simply read the measurements from the instrument or the text file, construct the appropriate webservice request and use a HTTPClient to POST data to the WebService.
3. On the computer write a simple web app to read the infromation from the MySQL DB and display it on a web page.